# Modifying Each Bars EdgeColor After Every If-Statement

Tags: matlab, graph, set, bar-chart

**Question:** How to change every single bar's `edgecolor` based on conducting a mathematical-comparison later in the code (we have two bar-graphs f3 and f4, each bar-graphs number of bars depends on `rowNosMaxSG`, where at max. it will be consisting of 14-bars).

Currently with the mathematical-if-statement below for changing `edgecolor`, unfortunately I am experiencing edge-color overlapping after each of the 3-if-statements are executed and this overlapping affects the whole bars of each graph, while I want to be able to control `edgecolor` of every single bar in each bar-graph based on the mathematical comparison.

Truncated Code (including the mathematical-comparison):

```
    f3= bar(SN, Shift_Grade', 'stacked', 'FaceColor', 'white');
    f4= bar( SN( Shift_Gradey ~= 0 ), Shift_Gradey( Shift_Gradey ~= 0 ),...
      'stacked', 'FaceColor', 'white', 'EdgeColor','green',...
      'LineWidth', 2);
%----------------   **Mathematical-Comparison (3-if-statements)**  --------------------
    if ( SN( Shift_Grade' <= 11.3 )
         set(f3, 'EdgeColor', 'r')
    end
    if  (  SN( 11.3 < Shift_Grade' ) & SN( Shift_Grade' < 16 ) )
         set(f3, 'EdgeColor', 'y')
    end
    if ( SN( Shift_Grade' >= 16 ) )
         set(f3, 'EdgeColor', 'g')
         set(f4, 'EdgeColor', 'g')
    end
set(gca, 'Xtick', 1:2:length(SN)+1)
set(gca,'YLim',[0 20])
set(gca,'XLim',[0 length(SN)+1])
```

Hoping for a crisp and clear answer to solve this problem that is hindering my progress. Thanks for your time in advance.

---

Good idea Doresoom, I didn't know about that. I have implemented your idea, but still I get this error for the code below:

??? Error using ==> `set`

Conversion to `double` from `cell` is not possible.

*A Reproducible Code:*

```
SN= [1:14]';
SG= [15.5; 13; 15; 12.2; 13.6; 13.4; 14.2; 9; 17.7; 15; 12.5; 10; 16; 13.6];
SN_UnderDogs= [8; 12];
SN_Mediocre= [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 10; 11; 14];
SN_Top= [9; 13];

for cc = 1:length(SN)
    f3(cc) = bar(cc, SG(cc), 'FaceColor', 'white');
end

if  SN( SG <= 11.3 )
    for SNUD = SN_UnderDogs ( 1 : length (SN_UnderDogs) )
        set(get(f3(SNUD),'Children'),'EdgeColor','r')
    end
end
if  SN( 11.3 < SG  &  SG < 16 )
    for SNM = SN_Mediocre ( 1 : length (SN_Mediocre) )
        set(get(f3(SNM),'Children'),'EdgeColor','y')
    end
end
if  SN( SG >= 16 )
    for SNT = SN_Top ( 1 : length (SN_Top) )
        set(get(f3(SNT),'Children'),'EdgeColor','g')
    end
end
```

How can I solve this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you include an image of what is currently happening and what it should actually look like?

Comment: Unfortunately I cant upload an image as I dont have enough reputation since I am new to this site. However, I have explained what is happening in the 2nd paragraph. If there is sth unclear pls let me know so I explain further.

Comment: Perhaps you can make a small reproducible example using `bar(1:10,1:12:120)` or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SN= [1:14]';
SG= [15.5; 13; 15; 12.2; 13.6; 13.4; 14.2; 9; 17.7; 15; 12.5; 10; 16; 13.6];
SN_UnderDogs= [8; 12];
SN_Mediocre= [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 10; 11; 14];
SN_Top= [9; 13];

for cc = 1:length(SN)
    f3(cc) = bar(cc, SG(cc), 'FaceColor', 'white');
    hold on;
end

if  SN( SG <= 11.3 )
    for SNUD = SN_UnderDogs ( 1 : length (SN_UnderDogs) )
        % set(get(f3(SNUD),'Children'),'EdgeColor','r')
        cellfun(@(x) set(x,'EdgeColor','r'), get(f3(SNUD),'Children'))
    end
end
if  SN( 11.3 < SG  &  SG < 16 )
    for SNM = SN_Mediocre ( 1 : length (SN_Mediocre) )
        % set(get(f3(SNM),'Children'),'EdgeColor','y')
        cellfun(@(x) set(x,'EdgeColor','y'), get(f3(SNM),'Children'))
    end
end
if  SN( SG >= 16 )
    for SNT = SN_Top ( 1 : length (SN_Top) )
        % set(get(f3(SNT),'Children'),'EdgeColor','g')
        cellfun(@(x) set(x,'EdgeColor','g'), get(f3(SNT),'Children'))
    end
end
```

Comment: Well, I thought you call `hold on` before making all `bar` calls - otherwise the code from you second post would crash in the same way. Nevertheless, I fixed the code in my post. Hope it helps.

Comment: Bravo! you saved my day once more! Thumbs-up.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried grabbing the patch handles of the bars themselves?

You may have to plot all the bars as separate bar graphs.
Something like this might work:

```
figure
hold on
for n = 1:10
bh(n) = bar(n,n);
end
set(get(bh(1),'Children'),'EdgeColor','r','FaceColor','w')
```

Comment: Thumbs up, as I have utilized your idea. Thanks also, user **miy** has solved the problem.

Comment: Oh, I see I cant tick more than one answer :( I will do it next time. Thanks